# GAE: Datastore writeback extremely delayed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the last 12 hours, we noticed two instances of severe delays in writeback to our HRD datastore:

(1) A new entity was saved on Feb-4-2013 9:58 PM EST (its ID was written to our server logs), but a look up via a one-to-one foreign key would not retrieve a result for over 4 hours until Feb-5-2013 2:17 AM EST.

(2) An entity was deleted on Feb-5-2013 1:51 AM EST, but 10 minutes later at 2:01 EST, it was still being returned in a query.

I filed an issue with GAE: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8776

We've never seen anything like this before, and it is twice in one night. Has anyone else observed this?

Comment: You didn't use ancestor queries, did you?
If you did, it would be a *serve* bug.
If you didn't, thats exactly the expected and *desired* behavior.
Theres a thing called "CAP-Theorem".
In the GAE, you explicitly sacrifice your consistent view on your data in favor of availability and partition-tolerance if not using ancestor queries.

Comment: No ancestor queries. I understand about the eventual consistency behavior, and my software is designed to be tolerant of that "to a point" (i.e., minutes). I would not expect nor have I ever seen a consistency model that takes 10 minutes to over 4 hours to complete. That sounds like an operational problem that needs to be publicized via Google's service status page.